# Trying to make a bar chart with each categorical column as a different color

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I found a cool Wes Anderson palette package but I am failing here in actually using it. The variable I am looking at (Q1) has options 1 and 2. There is an NA in the set which is getting plotted however I would like to remove it as well.

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(wesanderson)

RA_Survey <- read_excel("file extension")

ggplot(data = RA_Survey, mapping = aes(x = Q1)) +
  geom_bar() + scale_fill_manual(values=wes_palette(n=2, name="GrandBudapest"))
```

The plot I'm getting is working but without the color. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `ggplot(data = RA_Survey, aes(x = Q1, fill = factor(Q1))) +
  geom_bar()+ scale_fill_manual(values=wes_palette(n=2, name="GrandBudapest")) `

Comment: Error in wes_palette(n = 2, name = "GrandBudapest") : Palette not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues which need to be addressed.

#### Using the Wes Anderson palette

As already mentioned by [Mako](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52086252/trying-to-make-a-bar-chart-with-each-categorical-column-as-a-different-color#comment91122961_52086252), the `fill` aesthetic was missing from the call to `aes()`.

Furthermore, the OP [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52086252/trying-to-make-a-bar-chart-with-each-categorical-column-as-a-different-color#comment91125692_52086252) an error message saying *Palette not found*. The `wesanderson` package contains a list of available palettes:

```
names(wesanderson::wes_palettes)
```

> ```
>  [1] "BottleRocket1"  "BottleRocket2"  "Rushmore1"      "Rushmore"       "Royal1"         "Royal2"         "Zissou1"       
>  [8] "Darjeeling1"    "Darjeeling2"    "Chevalier1"     "FantasticFox1"  "Moonrise1"      "Moonrise2"      "Moonrise3"     
> [15] "Cavalcanti1"    "GrandBudapest1" "GrandBudapest2" "IsleofDogs1"    "IsleofDogs2"
> ```

There is no palette called `"GrandBudapest"` as requested in OP's code. Instead, we have to choose between `"GrandBudapest1"` and `"GrandBudapest2"`.

Also, the help file `help("wes_palette")` lists the available palettes.

Here is a working example which uses the dummy data created in the **Data** section below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(wesanderson)
ggplot(RA_Survey, aes(x = Q1, fill = Q1)) +
  geom_bar() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=wes_palette(n=2, name="GrandBudapest1"))
```

[image]

#### Removing NA

The OP has asked to remove the NAs from the set. There are two options:

1. Tell `ggplot()` to remove the NAs.
2. Remove the NAs from te data by filtering.

We can tell `ggplot()` to remove NAs when plotting the x axis:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(wesanderson)
ggplot(RA_Survey, aes(x = Q1, fill = Q1)) +
  geom_bar() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=wes_palette(n=2, name="GrandBudapest1")) +
  scale_x_discrete(na.translate = FALSE)
```

[image]

Note, this produces a warning message *Removed 3 rows containing non-finite values (stat_count).* To get rid of the message, we can use `geom_bar(na.rm = TRUE)`.

The other option removes the NAs from the data by filtering

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(wesanderson)
ggplot(RA_Survey %>% filter(!is.na(Q1)), aes(x = Q1, fill = Q1)) +
  geom_bar() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=wes_palette(n=2, name="GrandBudapest1"))
```

which creates exactly the same chart.

#### Data

As the OP has not provided a sample dataset, we need to create our own:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123L)
RA_Survey <- data_frame(Q1 = sample(c("1", "2", NA), 20, TRUE, c(3, 6, 1)))
RA_Survey
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 20 x 1
>    Q1   
>    <chr>
>  1 2    
>  2 1    
>  3 2    
>  4 1    
>  5 NA   
>  6 2    
>  7 2    
>  8 1    
>  9 2    
> 10 2    
> 11 NA   
> 12 2    
> 13 1    
> 14 2    
> 15 2    
> 16 1    
> 17 2    
> 18 2    
> 19 2    
> 20 NA
> ```

Comment: That worked perfectly; I'm new to R so I'm glad you have some serious tips!

Comment: So I am trying to do the same thing again however the WesAnderson package only allows three colors in a plot. This one has 7 that are needed so I'm trying a new package. This one features 10 possible choices that could be chosen however the code for color does not worl

Comment: ggplot(RA_Survey, aes(x = Q2, fill = Q2)) +
  geom_bar() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=brewer.pal(n = 7, name = 'PuBu')) +
  scale_x_discrete(na.translate = FALSE)

Comment: @JohnThomas, please, post a new question which includes either the data you want to plot using `dput()` or the code which you used to create the sample data. Also, please, post which libraries you have loaded. Your code does work for me if `Q2` is of type character. If `Q2` is numeric, `scale_fill_manual()` is the wrong function.